# "Duplicate local variable" and "void is an invalid type for the variable" errors

Tags: java, declaration, void

I keep getting those two errors and cannot seem to understand why. These errors suddenly appeared in other methods as well, further down the same class. I have tried to find double declarations but could not find any. Also, I have paid attention to to write a method within another method. Help will be much appreciated! :)

```
public void connectStudentToCourse(long studentID, String courseID)
{
    if (studentID >= 0 && courseID != null)
    {
        boolean flag = false;
        Course tempCourse = new Course(courseID);
        tempCourse = sData.getCourses().get( sData.getCourses().indexOf(courseID) );
        Student stu = new Student(studentID);
        stu = sData.getStudents().get( sData.getStudents().indexOf(studentID) );
        if (tempCourse != null &&  stu != null)
        {
            if (tempCourse.getPreCourses() != null)
                for (Course c : tempCourse.getPreCourses())
                {
                    for (Course passed : stu.getCompletedCourses())
                    {
                        if (passed.equals(c))
                            flag = true;
                    }
                    if (flag == false)
                    {
                        MyFileLogWriter.writeToLogFile("Failed to connect Student "+studentID+" to course "+courseID+"\n", false);  
                        return;
                    }
                    else flag = false;
                }
            if (tempCourse.addStudent(stu))
            {
                if (stu.addCourse(tempCourse))
                {
                    MyFileLogWriter.writeToLogFile("Student "+stu.getId()+" connected to course "+tempCourse.getCourseID()+" successfully\n", false);
                    return;
                }
                else            //RollBack
                    tempCourse.removeStudent(stu);
            }
        }
    }
    MyFileLogWriter.writeToLogFile("Failed to connect Student "+studentID+" to course "+courseID+"\n", false);
}
```

Comment: Make sure your brackets are balanced.

Comment: Where are the errors? Have you tried reducing this to a minimal example?

Comment: I suspect the problem is actually directly *before* this method - my guess is that you haven't got enough closing braces to close the previous method.

Comment: I have double checked the method above it and all brackets seem to be balanced and in order. Also, Eclipse did not mark anything as an error in the method above this one.

Comment: Also, in the method title, Eclipse suddenly expects me to space the input variables with a ";" instead of the usual "," : (long studentID ; String courseID) instead of (long studentID , String courseID) .

Comment: Unbalanced braces will show in mysterious places, so just because the previous method doesn't show the error, doesn't mean it's not the cause. The error Eclipse shows you indicates that @PM77-1 was very likely right. --- In Eclipse, when you place the cursor on a brace, it highlights the matching brace. Try that on the end-brace of the previous method. It'll likely highlight a start-brace on some if-statement.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to add opening bracket at 2nd if statement and close it, may it solve your problem...

Comment: It's a good idea to add those braces, but it won't fix the problem. The if statement is good without the braces, since it's a simple null guard for the loop.

Comment: Yes @Andreas your right, but this 2nd if without brackets only applied for first line so I think better to add brackets for this if.

Comment: Better? Yes. But it's not the *answer* to the problem.

Comment: Thank you all very much for your efforts!! Much appreciated!! I have also noticed one more thing that might give a clue. In the method above this one, The input variable names are suddenly not colored and appear in black, as opposed to other methods. They have been colored before so I suspect that something might have changed that made Eclipse not to recognize them and color them automatically as before.

Answer (score 0):

Only when I cut all the problematic methods from the class, I noticed a missing "}" in the method above them. Eclipse did not show this missing brace, only until I removed all the rest of the code, so I could not tell where was it missing until the removal. I added the missing brace and re-pasted the rest of the problematic methods back into the class, and all errors have vanished! Solution was much more simple than I expected it to be. @PM77-1, @Jon Skeet and @Andreas - you are all LEGENDS!! Thank you so much!! :)